# BlackBerry Lists best practise

Tags: list, blackberry

I'm developing BlackBerry 5.0 application with list organized data.
I'm using ObjectListField and manual drawing in overriden drawListRow. I'm afraid this is
wrong, because all positionig inside row si done manualy, and now I have
 serious problem how to handle click on small icon inside row. There must be some better way,
  maybe using other control or simple HorizontalFieldManager in VerticalFieldManager instead of ListField,
 what is recommended and best practise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case I would use a ListField and ListFieldCallback. You will still have to handle the drawing manually, but the ListField will handle the selection semantics. The selection will normally post a context menu for the ListField, but you can change that behaviour to invoke a default action if you want.

Comment: I just can't believe that TreeField ist best practise for lists.

Comment: Well, folders/files are naturally a hierachy where a parent node may contain many child nodes. That is a tree structure. If you want to implement it as a list, you could use the ListField but I think you would be re-implementing a lot of what the TreeField would give you.

Comment: oh sorry it's misunderstanding, I shouldn't mentioned files/folders  because it's always only current level of hierarchy displayed,
 so forget about  files/folders,  what's best practise for lists?  (I should edit question)